# Take screenshot/image of path/track recorded with GPS and save to memory

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, gps

I have developed an application which can track user's movements periodically and plot it on a google map using polylines. Everything works fine. I want to implement a function where when a button is pressed, the route/path recorded should be saved into the database to be able to retrieve later and view. It would be easier if I can save a screenshot/thumbnail of the map along with the route as an image. Then it can be shared on the social networks and stuff.

Any idea on how to convert the recorded route into an image using the v2 api?

Comment: Enable the drawing cache and get the bitmap from it?

Comment: I think first you can `setting boundaries` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#setting_boundaries) to get whole area, and then take a `screenshot`.